# Trying to fetch data from table with good performance

Tags: join, plsql, subquery

I am trying to fetch customer and owner data

**customer**
|**cnumber** |**id** |
|080204220 |32859471000|
|907501981|6029151000|

**role**
|**id**|**type**|
|32859471000|owner|
|6029151000|customer|

**result set**
**id**|**number**|**owner number**|**type**|
|32859471000|080204220 |080204220 | owner
|6029151000|907501981|080204220 |customer

**query**

```
select c.id,sub.cnumber,c.cnumber, r.roletype
from customer c 
inner join role r on c.id = r.id 
left outer join (select c.cnumber ,r.roletype,c.id
                     from customer c
                     INNER JOIN role r
                     ON c.id = r.id  ) sub on  sub.roletype='owner';
```

This query gives proper result, but left outer join with same tables may cause impact on performance, is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer you to go with this only.

```
select c.id,sub.cnumber,c.cnumber, r.roletype
from customer c 
inner join role r on c.id = r.id 
left outer join (select c.cnumber ,r.roletype,c.id
                     from customer c
                     INNER JOIN role r
                     ON c.id = r.id  ) sub on  sub.roletype='owner';
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can get the logic, you need to display an "owner"-customer among all of the others.

Since there is only one owner in the example data, I'd do it using the "cross join" (cartesian join)

```
select c.id,sub.cnumber,c.cnumber, r.roletype
  from customer c 
 inner join role r on c.id = r.id 
 cross join (select c.cnumber ,r.roletype,c.id
                 from customer c
                 INNER JOIN role r
                 ON c.id = r.id where r.roletype='owner') sub
```

Comment: Yes but again joining with the same table, my point is i am also using same tables in sub query so it will hit performance. So wanted to know is there any other way to achieve this

Comment: @Shine, I don't think so: you have to join 2 different queries anyway. One is to join customers and roles and another one is to display just the owner-customers

Comment: if there is no other way, i will continue with my query only. Thank u :-)

Comment: "May cause impact on performance", well does it actually. How many tests have you run. I would look at the indexes before attempting a rewrite.  Another "may": One or both of the results of the second join may already be in the buffer, thus preventing another physical I/O, thereby improving performance over some other query. This seems a classic example of premature optimization (Google:  *Donald Knuth premature optimization*).

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.id,sub.cnumber,c.cnumber, r.roletype
from customer c 
inner join role r on c.id = r.id 
left outer join (select c.cnumber ,r.roletype,c.id
                     from customer c
                     INNER JOIN role r
                     ON c.id = r.id  ) sub on  sub.roletype='owner';
```